# Am I gaming the system accidentally when I edit a post?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, voting, edits, exploit

I posted a response to [this question about SVN post-commit hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190218/trouble-with-svn-post-commit/2192979), and then noticed that the answer above mine could use an edit. Both answers had 0 votes at the time. When I edited the answer that preceded mine, it became the second answer in the question.  This seems wrong to me. It's intuitively obvious that the earlier answer is likely to get more votes, which means that I've just jumped the queue, so to speak, over someone who provided a decent answer very quickly.

I'm not sure there's a good way to fix this, but I figured I'd bring it to the mods' attention.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful responses, folks. I feel a lot better knowing that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answers at the same vote level, when in "highest voted order"  (default) mode, are shown in random order, so this is not affected by your edit.

In "newest first" edits don't "re-new" the answer, so it doesn't change the order either.

I suspect you were in "highest voted order" and it randomly put the one you edited higher, but the next user might see a different order.

Either way, don't worry about it.  As long as the edit was a worthwhile contribution, then you've improved the site.